# Excel: Formula to fill dates in a Weekly Calendar

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, calendar, organization

I found a template for an Excel monthly calendar and it works great for me. Each month is in its own sheet (Tab) and there is a formula that pre-populates the days of the month.

```
=DaysAndWeeks+DATE(CalendarYear,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalendarYear,1,1),(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+1
```

And it looks like this: (I guess I can't post images yet, but there is a link..)
[Monthly Calendar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ3rG.png)

The formula is used on the day of the month. In the image example for the month of January, the formula is displaying: 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc....

What I am trying to do is make a new Excel workbook with the Weeks of the Year.
It would follow the same format, one week per sheet (tab), so there would be 52 sheets + 1 in the beginning I will call template, that I can make changes to and copy to the week tabs. So I don't have to Change each one individually.

So I am looking for a formula that will fill in the DayOfWeek month/Day at the top of my week "table".
This is what I am using at the moment for my weekly calendar: (again, I can't post images, but its in the link)
[Weekly Calendar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfkbP.png)

The formula I am looking for will span the whole workbook (same as it does in my monthly calendar) and pre-populate the dates in each sheet.

Any Excel Wizards out there that can wave their wands?? =)

Thanks for any help. And if you guys want any of the workbooks to use, just let me know, I can share them. (btw, I use Excel 2016)

Answer (score 0):

In your post, it looks like the monthly calendar formula is referencing the cells under the "calendar settings."  For the weekly spreadsheet, you can use something like ==IFERROR(UPPER(TEXT(DATE(ReportYear,MonthNumber,ReportDay),"MM D")),"") which I pulled from https://templates.office.com/en-us/Daily-work-schedule-TM02780252 and formatted it to use "MM D".

I would appreciate you sharing the monthly calendar and I'll certainly give the weekly calendar a go as well if you wouldn't mind sharing.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I will have some free time later today or tomorrow to try this out, and I can share the calendars as well.

Comment: Sounds great, look forward to hearing from you. -Jason

Comment: I was not able to get the weekly formula to work, but if anyone would like, here is a link to the Monthly Calendar and Weekly Calendar. Let me know if it doesn't allow you to download it. I can change the settings.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1w4kAw481SHDk42N4es_uNBVzSN3tMfFm?usp=sharing